# cant replace line in Textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I can replace line in Textbox using this Function

```c
  void changeLine(TextBox RTB, int line, string text)
        {
            int s1 = RTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
            int s2 = line < RTB.Lines.Count() - 1 ?
                      RTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line + 1) - 1 :
                      RTB.Text.Length;
            RTB.Select(s1, s2 - s1);
            RTB.SelectedText = text;
        }
```

And then i call it like this

```c
 int linenumber = TextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("Hello: "));

                changeLine(TextBox1, linenumber, "Hello Evrey Body ");
```

It works perfect in Desktop APP. But i can't use it in my asp.net website.

The Error:

> "TextBox does not contain a definition for GetLineFromCharIndex"

How can i solve this?

Comment: Try pre-pending TextBox RTB with ref keyword?

Comment: Yes. Even i use TextBox1 direct. The method GetLineFromCharIndex doesn't exit in asp.net

Comment: As the error message indicates, you cannot call the GetLineFromCharIndex method on an instance of a text box.

Comment: is there any way in ASP to replace line in multi line TextBox ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You could replace the entire contents of the text box with something new. To be honest, it sounds like you need to revisit the requirements of your project. You are trying to treat a Web form control as if it were a desktop app and they are two entirely different things.

Comment: ok. i will think about another approach.